# Application Insights - Auto Instrumentation - Certain Sites Don't Show Up from Server, Others Do

Tags: azure-application-insights

I've successfully installed application insights auto-instrumentation on servers.

I've noticed a pattern where certain applications (root sites), the app insights data doesn't appear for these.

I'm using IIS and .NET 4+ (sadly ...)

The packages mentioned in the troubleshooting are not present and thus not causing an issue.

Comment: Please share your source code and configuration files.

Comment: its the auto-instrumentation via powershell/iis - there is no code

Comment: You can try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:
**1**.Verify that the Application Insights SDK is installed and configured correctly for the affected applications.
**2**.Check the IIS logs and event logs for any errors or warnings related to Application Insights.
**3**.Verify that the Application Insights telemetry is being sent from the affected applications by using the Live Metrics Stream in the Azure portal.

Comment: **4**.If the issue persists, you may want to consider using the Application Insights Profiler to diagnose the issue.The Profiler provides detailed information about the performance of your application, including the performance of the Application Insights SDK.

Comment: figured it out - all good - it's super old sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because they are old .NET sites and the httpRuntime isn't set, and they are older than 4.6.